# Degree $4$ polynomial $p$ such that $p(A) = 0$ for all $A \in M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Someone asked me how to prove that there exist real numbers $a_0, \ldots, a_4$ not all zero such that
$$
a_0 I_2 + a_1 A + a_2 A^2 + a_3 A^3 + a_4 A^4 = 0 \quad \forall A \in M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}),
$$
where $I_2$ is the identity matrix of dimension $2$. However I don't know how to handle this so I ask for any idea ? The only result I know of that looks like it might be of some help is the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, but here $A$ is general... In fact this result seems a little strange to me because of the generality of $A$. How is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any such 5-tuple. Proof: Choose any $r \in \mathbb R$ and take $A = r I$. Then the equation gives
$$ a_0 + a_1 r + a_2 r^2 + a_3 r^3 + a_4 r^4 = 0. $$
Since the LHS is a polynomial in $r$ with infinitely many roots it is the zero polynomial hence $a_0 = \cdots = a_4 = 0$.

Comment: There is no reason that all $a_i$ would need to be zero. More specifically, the polynomial $r^2I -2rA+A^2=0$ is a solution. That is $a_0=r^2, a_1=-2r, a_2=1, a_3=a_4=0$.

Comment: But the $a_i$ were assumed to be constants in $\mathbb R$, i.e. they can't depend on $r$.

Comment: r isn't fixed though, r is any arbitrary real number, so once we fix $a_0$, $a_1$,...,$a_4$ then we can pick any s not equal to r then s$I$ isn't a root of our polynomial

Comment: This is somewhat confusingly formulated (notably the part "for some $r\in\Bbb R$"). The essence is correct though: since you cannot make this happen for all the scalar matrices (or even for 5 of them), there is no hope to make it happen for _all_ $2\times2$ matrices.

Comment: Thanks @MarcvanLeeuwen, fixed.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by fixed. One should not _choose_ (i.e., fix) $r$, since then there is no meaning for the later "polynomial in $r$". Instead you should say something like: if this is to hold for all matrices $A=rI$ with $r\in\Bbb R$, then [equation] must hold for all $r$...